# Add UITabBarController NOT from the appDelegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Is it just me or literally ALL the examples that I have seen on the web for uitabbarcontroller require modifying the appDelegate? What if the tabbar comes later on in the app and there are some other screens before? Can someone explain this or point to an example where the first screen of the app is NOT a tabbar view? I am getting nuts from this and cant seem to be able to have the tabbar to work if not from the AppDelegate.

Thanks!!!

UPDATE:

So I am doing this in one of my view controllers in a method that triggers once you click on a button to move to the next screen (which is the tab bar view). It crashes during the execution:

```
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstView alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstView" bundle:nil];
UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondView" bundle:nil];
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil]; //CRASHES HERE
self.window.rootViewController = self.tabBarController;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Any idea why? Thanks!!

It crashes in this line:

```
self.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil]; //CRASHES HERE
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can push the *UITabBarController* to the navigation controller from any view controller. Doing so may collapse the navigation bars as the view controllers in *UITabBarController* may themselves contain *UINavigationController*.

In order to overcome this navigation bar issue, you need to hide the navigation bar of the current navigation controller from the view controller where you push the tab bar controller. Hide the navigation bar in *viewWillDisappear:* method of the current view controller.

```
- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated {

    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: +1 I am fine with this collapse, but where in the view controller should I push the UITabBarController? ViewDidLoad?

Comment: You should do it inside an action/method, probably a button's action.

Comment: so basically if I am now in a particular view controller, and after pushing the button i go to a tab bar view - is it enough to have only objects for the tabs (for example, TabOneViewController, TabTwoViewController, etc.) or do I need an additional object "in between" to implement all the tabbarcontroller?

Comment: Its enough if you just set up the tab bar controller with the view controllers and push it to navigation controller.

Comment: but when i push the tabbarcontroller - do i push the first view? second view or third view of my tabs? i am confused as to which viewcontroller is being pushed...:/

Comment: You have to push all the view controllers. First tab is selected by default.

Answer (score 1):

Ok here we go. Suppose mainWindow.xib has one UINavigationController and one TabBarController. First few screens are deisgned with navigation controller later at some point when you want tabBarController what you need to do is just remove the navigationController's view from mainWindow and add tabBarController's view as a subview to window. I hope you understand if not let me know.

Comment: +1 Not really...:/ do you have a sample code perhaps? Let's say my stack is the following: appDelegate, WelcomeScreenViewController, Then 3 tabs: FirstTabView, SecondTabView and ThirdTabView - where should I do all those things?

Comment: In your App Delegate.  You could add a message in the .h of your App Delegate, and message from your other controller if it is initiated by some user interaction (for example).

Comment: My whole question was about not using the appdelegate though...any other options? thanks!

Comment: Yes you can add a parentView controller to manage all these tasks but appDelegate is better approach.

Answer (score 1):

> Because the UITabBarController class inherits from the UIViewController class, tab bar controllers have their own view that is accessible through the view property. When deploying a tab bar interface, you must install this view as the root of your window. Unlike other view controllers, a tab bar interface should never be installed as a child of another view controller.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: And that means in English that? :) Read this but not sure what it means with respect to the appDelegate...

Comment: That you should ONLY use a UITabBarController when you use it as the root/first/main viewcontroller in the appdelegate. You should not push on a UITabBarController, should you need something like this behavior you should use UIToolBar even though it is not as good, unfortunate.